# Meaning C[-16]:C[-17]

Tags: vba, excel

What does `C[-16]:C[-17]` mean in VBA for Excel 2016 on Win10 in below code?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP([@[" & Chr(10) & "numberr]],'" & temp & "'!C[-16]:C[-17],2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: `C[-16]` means 16 columns to the left using `R1C1` , and it's not related to whatever version of Excel or Windows you are using

Comment: To the left from where? If is possible can you explain me also what mean "2" and FALSE also? Thanks.

Comment: From your current cell, so if ActiveCell is Range("R1") which is column 18, so -16 columns will be column B

Comment: If the code is working well, on the next line write `MsgBox ActiveCell.Formula` and it will show you the exact formula the code is translated to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel supports [2 different reference styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-referencestyle-property-excel) - `xlR1C1` and `xlA1`. The `xlA1` style is the most common one, where the columns are with the alpha characters. The `xlR1C1` style, the columns and the rows are displayed with numbers. In your case `C[-16]:C[-17]` is a range which is starting from the 16. column to the left and finishing with the 17. column to the left.

To see the difference, try this code line by line with <kbd>F8</kbd> and take a look at range `A1`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
    ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = True

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that every month i add new row and because of that i'm changing C[] : C[] cells. But everytime I am getting values from A and B. Can I instead of editing everymonth this values, hardcode this with first and second row? A:B ? Thanks again.

Comment: @rivaq45 - if you add a new row, you should not be changing the values of the columns I guess.

Comment: @rivaq45 yes, change the reference to absolute `C1:C2`  This will now return the address `$A:$B`